# Asynchronous python function to process PHP

Tags: python, asynchronous, pyqt, pyqt5

I am developing an app with pyqt5 that works as a web application through QtWebChannel, when you click on the button with "Python" text of the html, a js function (login_py) is executed that recovers the value of an input (#request ) and shows a gif (loader.gif) that indicates that the request is being processed, then sends that value to python by backend and executes the php_function function by python that processes a call from a php file (login.php), once which ends, removes the gif and the php response is placed in a span (#response).

My problem is that when the "Python" button is pressed, the app window freezes temporarily and it is not pleasant that this happens, in addition, the gif that indicates that it is loading never appears, I would like to know if the request could be made a way more similar to a request for ajax, where the window does not freeze.

Alternatively, there is a button with text "Javascript" that processes the request by ajax, which would be as I would like the request for the "Python" button to be.

I clarify that the original login.php file tends to take an unknown time to respond, so as not to place the entire original code, I leave this modified login.php that simulates my situation.

**login.php**

```php
<?php
error_reporting(0);
sleep(5);
header("Content-type: application/json");
if ($argv[1]) {
    $var = $argv[1];
} else {
    $var = $_GET['one'];
}
echo '{"one":"'.$var.'"}';
?>
```

**test.py**

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets, QtWebChannel
import json
import os

#path = "http://localhost/test.html"
path = "test.html"
dirr = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), path)

class Backend(QtCore.QObject):
    valueChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._value = ""

    @QtCore.pyqtProperty(str)
    def value(self):
        return self._value

    @value.setter
    def value(self, v):
        self._value = v
        self.valueChanged.emit(v)

class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.webEngineView = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView()
        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        lay.addWidget(self.webEngineView)
        backend = Backend(self)
        backend.valueChanged.connect(self.php_function)
        self.channel = QtWebChannel.QWebChannel()
        self.channel.registerObject("backend", backend)
        self.webEngineView.page().setWebChannel(self.channel)
        #self.webEngineView.setUrl(QtCore.QUrl(path))
        self.webEngineView.setUrl(QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile(dirr))

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str)
    def php_function(self, value):
        data = os.popen('php login.php ' + value).read()
        data = json.loads(data)
        self.webEngineView.page().runJavaScript('$("#loader").removeAttr("src"); $("#response").text("'+data["one"]+'");')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**test.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="qrc:///qtwebchannel/qwebchannel.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var backend = null;
if (typeof QWebChannel !== "undefined") {
    new QWebChannel(qt.webChannelTransport, function (channel) {
        backend = channel.objects.backend;
    });
}
function login_py(request) {
    $("#loader").attr("src", "loader.gif");
    backend.value = request;
}
function login_js(request) {
    $("#loader").attr("src", "loader.gif");
    $.ajax({
        url: 'login.php',
        type: 'get',
        data: {one:request},
        success: function (data) {
            $("#loader").removeAttr("src");
            $("#response").text(data.one);
        }
    })
}
</script>
<body>
<input id="request">
<button onclick="login_js($('#request').val())">Javascript</button>
<button onclick="login_py($('#request').val())">Python</button>
<br>
<br>
<img id="loader">
<span id="response"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`os.popen()` is a blocking task that will freeze the event loop of Qt causing the GUI to freeze, so you must replace that method with a method that does not block such as using `QProcess` or in the extreme case run it on another thread, in this case it is enough to use QProcess and send the information asynchronously.

```py
import json
import os

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets, QtWebChannel


current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
# path = "http://localhost/test.html"
path = "test.html"
dirr = os.path.join(current_dir, path)


class Backend(QtCore.QObject):
    valueChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._value = ""

    @QtCore.pyqtProperty(str, notify=valueChanged)
    def value(self):
        return self._value

    @value.setter
    def value(self, v):
        self._value = v
        self.valueChanged.emit(v)


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.webEngineView = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView()
        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        lay.addWidget(self.webEngineView)
        backend = Backend(self)
        backend.valueChanged.connect(self.php_function)
        self.channel = QtWebChannel.QWebChannel()
        self.channel.registerObject("backend", backend)
        self.webEngineView.page().setWebChannel(self.channel)
        # self.webEngineView.setUrl(QtCore.QUrl(path))
        self.webEngineView.setUrl(QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile(dirr))

        self._php_process = PhpProcess()
        self._php_process.resultChanged.connect(self.process_php_result)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str)
    def php_function(self, value):
        self._php_process.execute(value)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str)
    def process_php_result(self, data):
        data = json.loads(data)
        self.webEngineView.page().runJavaScript(
            '$("#loader").removeAttr("src"); $("#response").text("'
            + data["one"]
            + '");'
        )


class PhpProcess(QtCore.QObject):
    resultChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._process = QtCore.QProcess(self)
        self._process.readyReadStandardOutput.connect(self.on_readyReadStandardOutput)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str)
    def execute(self, parameter):
        self._process.start("php", [os.path.join(current_dir, "login.php"), parameter])

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_readyReadStandardOutput(self):
        output = self._process.readAllStandardOutput()
        self.resultChanged.emit(output.data().decode())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: It was just what I needed, indeed, the os.popen() to freeze the guide, QProcess is the best solution in my case, thanks for the clarification. Cheers